# Unable to link against FFmpeg libaries

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg, debian

I tried to build this, but always got link-time error.

```
#include <libavutil/log.h>    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::av_log_set_flags(AV_LOG_SKIP_REPEATED);
    return 0;
}
```

My distro is Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). The FFmpeg was built by myself, and the configure command was...

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-static --enable-shared \
> --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib'
```

The link-error is as follows.

```
$ g++ foo.cpp -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Wall \
> -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib \
> $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libavutil)
/tmp/ccKzgEFb.o: In function `main':
foo.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `av_log_set_flags(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

where the output of `pkg-config` is...

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libavutil
-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lavutil
```

The `objdump` shows that the shared object libavutil.so does have `av_log_set_flogs` inside.

```
$ objdump --dynamic-syms /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so | grep 'av_log_set_flags'
000260f0 g    DF .text  0000000a  LIBAVUTIL_54 av_log_set_flags
```

Please note that the `g++` command used to build the above application had a linker option `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib`, though it still doesn't work. Also, I've tried to monitor with `inotifywait` if the other version provided by the distro were called. They were not, and the one being opened during execution of `g++` was /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.

Summary:

1. /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so does have the symbol.
2. `-rpath` was used to force to link against the shared library.
3. Why link-time error? T_T

Any suggestion or information would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

REEDIT: `ffplay` works fine and `ldd` shows it use /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so. So, the libraries seems not broken, and the problem becomes how to build my own codes to use the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This had me baffled too for a while. I managed to google this: http://soledadpenades.com/posts/2009/linking-with-ffmpegs-libav/

It turns out `FFMPEG` don't make their header files `C++` aware.

Here is the fix:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/log.h>
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ::av_log_set_flags(AV_LOG_SKIP_REPEATED);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to wrap all `ffmpeg` header includes with `extern "C"` linkage.

Comment: stackoverflow says "don't use comment to say thank you", but I really really thank you. T_T. You saved my life, sir. I was so desperate on this that there even voices asking me to just suicide. Thank you so much, Galik.