# How to compile FFmpeg with libx265 for Android?

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, libx265

I have compiled FFmpeg with libx264(as static library) for Android successfully. But I want to use libx265(as static library) in FFmpeg on Android, too. So I have made some attempts:

First, I fixed libx265's log2 function and posix_memalign function not found problems by changing them into log(use log to approximate log2) function and memalign(to replace posix_memalign and do some adjustments) function. And fixed the pthread-linking problem by removing "-lpthread" in the cmakelist.txt file.

Then, I used cmake and make to compile libx265(as static library) successfully.

I enabled libx265 while FFmpeg configure. But when the configure ran, it showed "libx265 not found using pkg-config" on the screen.

I checked the config.log, and found these error message:

```
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(bitstream.cpp.o):bitstream.cpp:typeinfo for x265::BitInterface: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(bitstream.cpp.o):bitstream.cpp:typeinfo for x265::Bitstream: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(encoder.cpp.o):encoder.cpp:typeinfo for x265::SEIDecodedPictureHash: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(encoder.cpp.o):encoder.cpp:typeinfo for x265::SEIuserDataUnregistered: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(encoder.cpp.o):encoder.cpp:typeinfo for x265::SEIMasteringDisplayColorVolume: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(threading.cpp.o):threading.cpp:typeinfo for x265::Thread: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(wavefront.cpp.o):wavefront.cpp:typeinfo for x265::JobProvider: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(slicetype.cpp.o):slicetype.cpp:typeinfo for x265::BondedTaskGroup: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(frameencoder.cpp.o):frameencoder.cpp:function x265::FrameEncoder::encodeSlice(): error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(frameencoder.cpp.o):frameencoder.cpp:function x265::FrameEncoder::encodeSlice(): error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(frameencoder.cpp.o):frameencoder.cpp:function x265::FrameEncoder::processRowEncoder(int, x265::ThreadLocalData&): error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(frameencoder.cpp.o):frameencoder.cpp:function .LTHUNK2: error: undefined reference to '__dynamic_cast'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(frameencoder.cpp.o):frameencoder.cpp:typeinfo for x265::FrameEncoder: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/lib/libx265.a(sei.cpp.o):sei.cpp:typeinfo for x265::SEI: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info'
/home/user/ffmpeg-2.8.1/android/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
```

How should I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546154/unable-to-link-against-ffmpeg-libaries/32546363#32546363

Comment: If I use shared library, it will work. I think there are some libraries or functions I didn't link.

Comment: Is that possible to post your /makefile/.configure file/script for arm? @user3032481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I need to add the 「libgnustl_static.a」's path to the gcc/g++ as parameters manually. After do that, the compilation will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

recently i just meet the error, and just as user3032481 said.

i modify the configure of ffmpeg as below.

```
--extra-libs="-lother_libs -L/Users/shutup/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi -lgnustl_static" \
```

i think,the reason is that x265 need c++ rtti feature,but android default libstdc++ do not contain it. so we need add libgnustl_static.a .